# Can I consider my OS safe after I installed a firewall?

Tags: firewall

After Ubuntu 20 installation, I installed a firewall with main options:

```
$ sudo ufw allow ssh
Rules updated
Rules updated (v6)
$ sudo ufw enable
Firewall is active and enabled on system startup
$ sudo ufw default deny incoming
Default incoming policy changed to 'deny'
(be sure to update your rules accordingly)
$ sudo ufw default allow outgoing
Default outgoing policy changed to 'allow'
(be sure to update your rules accordingly)
$ sudo ufw status numbered
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 2] 22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

I wonder, can I consider my composer safe?
I do not need other people/applications to have access to the content of my OS.
I have `apache` installed only for internal access.

Do I need to take some additional steps?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Have I to take some additive steps?" Ubuntu out of the box IS as safe as it gets; all incomming traffic is blocked unless you install software that allows it. Please do not ask for opinions "I wonder can I consider my composer safe ?" is not going to be answered.

Comment: Good security is more a set of good habits and a bit of learning instead of a single magic application. Firewalls originally became a popular workaround back in the 1990s because Windows had exploitable services listening for connections that the user could not control nor disable (they fixed that problem long ago). Ubuntu never had that problem. A good introduction to smart security is the [Ubuntu Security Podcast](https://ubuntusecuritypodcast.org/)

Answer (score 1):

At some point its  put you in safe side, Better than nothing.
Here is some others tips but not limited, that can make it to be more secure.

1. Choose Disk Encryption
2. Make sure the Important security updates option is turned on
3. Many free extensions are available to improve the security of your browser
4. Locking root for ssh login